# High precision html5 media player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

I have an html5 media player element with WebM format and my goal is to be able to play the segments in it with super high accuracy (up to 10ms). It's easy to set an accurate start time of segment, but I have issues with stopping playback at a given moment.
For example, stop 10-second media file exactly when it reaches the middle(5 seconds).

Initial idea was to pause the player by a timer, but I did not succeed in that. Even if I run the checks within 10ms interval it does not pause the player at exact moment - due to timer delays and not immediate processing of pause action - it stops up to 100ms later.

So my current idea is that maybe I can somehow extract part of the media from one player to another so that the new player instance will contain only the segment I need? Is it doable? Can I somehow copy only part of the "buffer" from player1 to player2?

Thank you